# How to create Vector3 for all resolutions

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to fit my interface for all resolutions. I have this code

```
private void OnEnable() {
    GameObject back = Instantiate(Background) as GameObject;

    BoxCollider2D back_bc2d = back.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

    float x = ((Screen.currentResolution.width) / back_bc2d.size.x) / 2;
    float y = (Screen.currentResolution.height / back_bc2d.size.y);

    back.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, back.transform.localScale.z);
    Destroy(back_bc2d);       
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create something like GUI.DrawTexture (I don't want to use GUI.DrawTexture because of some reasons)
My texture have to draw on a half screen.
But on different resolutions it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen resolution does not mean anything in world space, only the aspect ratio is important there. The in game geometry size is the same in every resolution, only the viewport may be wider showing more of it - this is how the camera works.

Also, you should not derive `localScale` used in world space from screen space coordinates - they don't work this way.

If you want to position some geometry in worldspace relative to the camera, use http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html